# Xdebug 3 Not Working With PhpStorm and WSL2 (Ubuntu 20.04)

Tags: phpstorm, xdebug, windows-subsystem-for-linux

Xdebug 3, WSL2 (Ubuntu 20.04) and PhpStorm is my set up. I have no idea what's wrong!

My ini settings:

```ini
xdebug.mode=debug 
xdebug.discover_client_host=1 
xdebug.client_host=10.0.0.107 (windows IP address)
xdebug.client_port=9003 
xdebug.idekey=PHPSTORM
```

---

PhpStorm setting screenshots:

[image: PhpStorm PHP Debug Settings.]

[image: PhpStorm CLI Interpreter]

Error on Validation:

[image: Web Server Validation]

---

Manually click Debug on a specific file in PhpStorm gives me this log:

```
[5669] [Step Debug] INFO: Checking remote connect back address.
[5669] [Step Debug] INFO: Checking header 'HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'.
[5669] [Step Debug] INFO: Checking header 'REMOTE_ADDR'.
[5669] [Step Debug] WARN: Could not discover client host through HTTP headers, connecting to configured address/port: 192.168.64.1:9000. :-|
[5669] [Step Debug] INFO: Connected to debugging client: 192.168.64.1:9000 
(fallback through xdebug.client_host/xdebug.client_port). :-)
```

But still my auto breakpoints while browsing site locally or running it through CLI are never triggered.

Comment: **1.** Is 10.0.0.107 is an IP address returned by `cat /etc/resolv.conf` run in WSL? See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/compare-versions#accessing-windows-networking-apps-from-linux-host-ip for more info. If not - please adjust **2.** Enable XDebug logging & check what it says: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/troubleshooting-php-debugging.html#collect-xdebug-logs

Comment: That returned a different IP, I was using result of ipconfig on windows side. I changed to that IP and breakpoints still never hit. Also log file never updates, unless I right click a file in PhpStorm and clicked edit. In which case log starts with what I added to bottom of my question.

Comment: 1. please remove `xdebug.discover_client_host=1`. 2. What does xdebug log says after `[5669] [Step Debug] INFO: Connected to debugging client: 192.168.64.1:9000`?

Comment: Removed the line but still does not work. Xdebug after that line is debug info. ```[6766] [Step Debug] -> <init xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" fileuri="file:///var/www/test.php" language="PHP" xdebug:language_version="7.4.3" protocol_version="1.0" appid="6766" idekey="10264"><engine version="3.0.4"><![CDATA[Xdebug]]></engine><author><![CDATA[Derick Rethans]]></author><url><![CDATA[https://xdebug.org]]></url><copyright><![CDATA[Copyright (c) 2002-2021 by Derick Rethans]]></copyright></init> ```

Comment: Note that just happens when right clicking a file and clicking debug. Breakpoints never trigger while browsing the website even with Run -> Start listening... and Break at first line.

Comment: **1.** Do you have "Listen for incoming for incoming connections" for XDebug enabled? See https://i.gyazo.com/dd827e33c466651e90f050d60f947b87.png **2.** Do you have any **Servers** configured at Settings | Languages & Frameworks | PHP | Servers (or just PHP | Servers)? If you do - try removing them & then try debugging again.

Comment: Yes listen is on, and no servers configured. But even configuring them does nothing.

Comment: 1. Please remove "Ignore external connections through unregistered server configurations" checkbox at Settings | Languages & Frameworks | PHP | Debug 2. Try debugging again and attach a full xdebug log

Comment: I have unchecked and checked that to no avail, also the xdebug.log is never written on normal browsing of the website, so its entirely empty unfortunately. The only time that file has data (I pasted above) is when manually right clicking s file in PhpStorm and clicking debug, and log only has what I posted.

Comment: please run `phpinfo();` webpage and check xdebug options listed there. Make sure there's `xdebug.mode=debug` in the output. You can also share the output here.

Comment: Yeah, xdebug mode is shown as debug. All my other values like port and client_host are shown too. This is quite confusing.

Comment: If there's nothing written in xdebug log - then xdebug session wasn't initiated. It is initiated either via special trigger or via "start automatically" instruction, see <https://xdebug.org/docs/step_debug#activate_debugger>. Try adding `xdebug.start_with_request=yes` to php.ini & check if this helps.

Comment: I tried that, but no changes. However debug level 7 shows this:

Comment: [22228] Log opened at 2021-05-11 16:01:12.309721
[22228] [Step Debug] INFO: Connecting to configured address/port: 192.168.64.1:9000.
[22228] [Step Debug] INFO: Connected to debugging client: 192.168.64.1:9000 (through xdebug.client_host/xdebug.client_port). :-)
[22228] [Step Debug] -> <init xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" fileuri="file:///var/www/test/int/page/index.php" language="PHP" xdebug:language_version="7.4.3" protocol_version="1.0" appid="22228" idekey="PHPSTORM"><engine version="3.0.4"><![CDATA[Xdebug]]></engine>

Comment: Guessing issue is on PhpStorm side?

Comment: Is this the only line in a log? Sorry, it's a bit difficult to keep track of the issue in this format. Can you contact us directly via Help | Contact Support? That way you can simply  send us all required log files: this would ease up the communication a lot.

Comment: Thanks for all the help, finally found a solution. Think the default PHP interpeters between windows and wsl were causing issues, I checked "Visible for only this project" in the windows and wsl projects and PhpStorm triggers breakpoints now.

Comment: Strange that it helped, but I'm happy to hear this works now

Comment: @Dmitrii Thank you, just saved me a big ol' pain